# bool function failure to return true or false

Tags: c++, class, boolean

My class method that I'm writing has to store the words into different arrays but also has to return a boolean of whether or not the file was successfully read in. Everything looks fine but I can't find the logic error.

The type of file I am reading in something like this, where the space is separated by a tab

```
misspelledword     correctword
misspelledword2     correctword2
misspelledword3     correctword3
```

but the format can also be like this

```
misspelledword     correctword correctword correctword
```

Here's my code

```
bool SpellChecker::loadFile(string filename)
{

    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(filename.c_str());
    if (ifile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(ifile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        getline (iss, misspelled[count], '\t');
        getline (iss, correct[count]);
        count++;
    }
    if (ifile.good())
    {
        return true;
    }
    ifile.close();
}
```

Not sure why it shouldn't return either false or true but it's returning a random number 17, not sure where it came from?

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement at the end. And also, a `bool` can't contain a `17`, please post a [mcve].

Comment: The compiler should be giving a warning. Turn on/up the warning level if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement if the loop fails, so the return value will be undefined. The compiler should have warned you about that.

Also, `good()` returns false if EOF has been reached. So you need to check for `eof()` and/or `!fail()` instead of `good()`.

Try something more like this:

```
bool SpellChecker::loadFile(string filename)
{
    ifstream ifile(filename.c_str());
    if (!ifile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    string line;
    int count = 0;

    while (getline(ifile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        getline(iss, misspelled[count], '\t');
        getline(iss, correct[count]);
        ++count;
    }

    return ifile.eof() && !ifile.fail();
    // or simply:
    // return (bool) ifile;
}
```

Alternatively, enable exception handling on I/O errors:

```
bool SpellChecker::loadFile(string filename)
{
    ifstream ifile;
    string line;
    int count = 0;

    ifile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit);
    try
    {
        ifile.open(filename.c_str());

        while (getline(ifile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            getline(iss, misspelled[count], '\t');
            getline(iss, correct[count]);
            ++count;
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure &)
    {
        cout << "Error opening or loading file" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```